# Spring Data Gemfire store java.lang.Class field

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

In my code I have a generic "Value" POJO, which contains value itself and it's class:

```
public class Value<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    private T value;
    private Class<T> type;

    ...

}
```

I am using Spring Data GemFire and "repositories" feature of Spring Data (the DAOs are created automatically from interfaces). When Spring creates DAO for this bean I got:

`FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.Class constructor accessible`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conditionProcessor': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalStatusElementDAO': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.Class constructor accessible
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalStatusElementDAO': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.Class constructor accessible
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:445) ~[spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:419) ~[spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:544) ~[spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:304) ~[spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.Class constructor accessible
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(AccessibleObject.java:139) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:129) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:444) ~[spring-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PreferredConstructor.<init>(PreferredConstructor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:79) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:62) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.GemfirePersistentEntity.<init>(GemfirePersistentEntity.java:40) ~[spring-data-gemfire-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.GemfireMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(GemfireMappingContext.java:38) ~[spring-data-gemfire-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.GemfireMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(GemfireMappingContext.java:29) ~[spring-data-gemfire-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:246) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:579) ~[spring-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:260) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:171) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:140) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:66) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.repository.support.GemfireRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(GemfireRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-gemfire-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.repository.support.GemfireRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(GemfireRepositoryFactory.java:97) ~[spring-data-gemfire-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:153) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:43) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144) ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

How can I store `java.lang.Class` in GemFire with Spring Data?

*UPD*:

```
public interface GlobalStatusElementDAO
  extends CrudRepository<GlobalStatusElement, String>
{
}

@Region("xxx")
public class GlobalStatusElement<T extends Serializable>
  extends Value<T>
{
  public GlobalStatusElement( final Class<T> type )
  {
    super( type );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: I really meant the full thing, with `BeanCreationException` and the wrapping exceptions. I'd like to see why/where/from what it's trying to create a `Class` object. Your configuration wouldn't hurt as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, this bean does not have a cache region, it is a part of another entity.

Comment: I don't know gemfire (or maybe you aren't showing us something), so I'll suggest this: try to figure out why Spring is trying to create a `Value` object by creating and injecting a `Class` object. Do you have `javax.annotation` annotations on your `globalStatusElementDAO` bean's class? Can we see that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it's not trying to create value. It fails on metadata creation stage. (`PreferredConstructorDiscoverer`) `globalStatusElementDAO` does not have any annotations, it is configured with `<gfe-data:repositories base-package="a.b.c.dao" />`

Comment: Let's see the `globalStatusElementDAO` bean class.

Comment: I think I'll write custom serializer for this field or bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class objects are generally not amenable to serialising via reflection. It is significantly easier to simply store the full class name and instantiate the class object from the name when you need it.

You could achieve this by either changing your `Value` class to store the class name as a `String` instead of the class object, or by changing how `Value` gets serialised.

For the second option, this can be done either by making `Value` implement `DataSerializable`, or by registering a `DataSerializer` for `Value`